# Convert 8 bytes into a Double in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, double

I'm reading an ancient data file that is basically a flattened object store with type flags - for instance, 1=Int16, 2=Int32. To read the Int32's, for instance, I read 4 bytes out of the stream and then did this:

```
If B.Length >= 2 + Offset Then
    Ans = Convert.ToUInt16(B(1 + Offset) * 256 + B(0 + Offset))
End If
```

Now I am at a bit of a loss how to do the 3=Double. These are 8-byte values, IEEE I assume. There is a `Convert.ToDouble(byte)`, but that's not the same thing, that just returns a Double containing a value from 0 to 255. Likewise, `Convert.ToDouble(Int64)` basically just casts the value to Double.

So what's the trick here? I found threads for doing it in VB6 and C, but not VB.net.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `BitConverter.ToDouble(byte_array)` ?

Comment: You might also want to consider the [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Plutonix; yup, works like a champ. Much faster too, ditched all my own conversions.